# MySQL Text Data Type Too Much?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have about 200 characters I'm trying to insert into my database under the data type longtext and I've also tried normal text.

With longtext it lets me fit a bit more although when I try to type about 200 characters it shows that it is too long according to the MySQL error.

I'm not sure how this works as LONGTEXT can store up to 4gb of characters.

Structure:

[image]

Let me know if you need any other information!

By the way its inserting into the database using a MySQLi Query from the POST Data.

Error:

[image]

Query:

```
$q = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `lunar_casino`.`posts`(`id`, `by`, `title`, `message`, `image`, `category`, `date`) VALUES(NULL, '$user', '$title', '$message', '$image', '$category', NOW())");
if(!$q){
   echo "<font color='red'><b>There has been an error with our database! Please contact the website administrator!</b></font><br /><br />";
   echo $mysqli->error;
} else {
   echo "<font color='green'><b>You have successfully added a blog post!</b></font><br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Have you logged the SQL query in PHP to make sure it's not a syntax error?

Comment: post your query instead of image

Comment: The  error  message at the bottom of the screencap clearly indicates you're suffering from an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-ables.com). This has NOTHING to do with the text's length and EVERYTHING to do with the fact that you're stuffing that text into your queries without any SQL injection defense methods

Comment: If you have at most 200 characters, use varchar instead of text of longtext.

Comment: @MarcB, your grammar is a bit wrong there it leads me to believe its under attack rather than just a SQL error.

Comment: yes, it is an attack. just because your payload is "Innocent" and not actually doing anything bad doesn't mean it's not a problem. the fix for your problem is also the fix for sql injection attacks in general.

Comment: I don't believe you understand @MarcB, although its okay. Maybe what you're trying to say is correct and there are just English issues here. I understand as obviously not everyones first language is English.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with size, you have an SQL error. You do not use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) correctly, and seem to be pasting data verbatim in the query.

You can tell by the actual SQL error you are getting:

> "... for the right syntax near 'm not making it...".

The `'` character screws up the query.

To fix correctly, use a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `lunar_casino`.`posts` (`id`, `by`, `title`, `message`, `image`, `category`, `date`) VALUES(NULL, :user, :title, :message, :image, :category, NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param(":user", $user);
$stmt->bind_param(":title", $title);
...etc...

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Ohhh now I get it. So what would I do a preg_replace of ' with \'?

Comment: No. Use a prepared statement. I linked to the docs and gave a (very rudimentary) example.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in blogpost.php on line 87

Comment: @user3023566 that can mean that prepare() returns false/null. Do you have display_errors set to true and error_reporting to E_ALL?

Comment: @user3023566 try dumping `$mysqli->error` then (after you've called `prepare()`) to see if there is any error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':user, :title, :message, :image, :category, NOW())' at line 1